# Grab text between tag and specific property names and store into PHP array

Tags: php, preg-match

i have a question, if i want to grab ALL the product names in url http://www.tokopedia.com/lbagstore

in the url above will display all products

i see in the View Source menu product name is between tag

```
<b itemprop="name"> [product name] <b>
```

i have PHP script like below:

```
<? 
$html=file_get_contents("https://www.tokopedia.com/lbagstore");
preg_match("'<b itemprop=\"name\">(.*?)</b>'si", $html, $match);
$productname = $match[1];
echo $productname;
?>
```

but it seems all blank page.

i have difficulty especially to put in array and display them all

does anyone can help me to fix this code? Thanks!

Comment: simple. don't use regexes. uses DOM and XPATH: `//b[@itemprop="name"]/text()`

Comment: hi thanks for responding does your script can be engaged inside PHP script just like that? i really need full code pals do you mind

Comment: http://php.net/dom

Answer (score 1):

You are "inspecting" the html code of the page instead of "displaying the SOURCE CODE". If you want to extract the data from a website, you need to display its source code, then you can get what you want from it using a regex.

I checked the code myself and there are no `<b itemprop="name"> [product name] <b>` within the source code, that's why you don't have any results. The only way to see that piece of code was to inspect the code displayed instead of the source code ;)

If you change your code to this, you will be able to see what the real code looks like and then you will be able to adapt your regex to grab the names of the products you want.

```
$html = "https://www.tokopedia.com/lbagstore";
var_dump($html);
preg_match("'<b itemprop=\"name\">(.*?)</b>'si", $html, $match);
$productname = $match[1];
echo $productname;
```

Just add the var_dump to display the text. Also if you can't scrap what you want from the website and you need to do it quick, i may recommand you a free google chrome extension called "grepsr" (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/grepsr), I tested it and i could extract the names of the products within 5 minuts.

edit : Also if you want to grab the name of all the products in the page you will have to use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php).

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Hello alex.. you have 2 answer that i tried: first using var_dump is great but it has difficulty grabbing on next page. and your second solution is so great. i will learn more how to grab all details when  link clicked. thanks aleX you saved me